# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when using SectionList

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I call an api to get my `movieData` API: https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/getCloseTime?city=Hsinchu&sTime=18&eTime=21

I think the data is correct for `SectionList`, the data is an array with lots of object, but i still get the error:

`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Can't figure it out how to fix the data problem ?

Here is `console.log(movieData);`:

[image]

Here is about my class component render:

```
render() {
    const movieData = this.props.searchTime;

    if (this.props.loading) {
      return <Spinner text='Loading...' />;
    }
    console.log('movieData =>');
    console.log(movieData);

    return (
      <View>
        <SectionList
          renderSectionHeader={this.sectionComp}
          renderItem={this.renderSectionItem}
          sections={movieData}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View><Text></Text></View>}
          ListHeaderComponent={() => <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#25B960', alignItems: 'center', height: 30 }}><Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff' }}>Header</Text></View>}
          ListFooterComponent={() => <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#25B960', alignItems: 'center', height: 30 }}><Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff' }}>Footer</Text></View>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If i set a test data `testSections` instead of `movieData` its working.

```
const testSections = [
  { key: "A", data: [{ title: "test1-1" }, { title: "test1-2" }, { title: "test1-3" }] },
  { key: "B", data: [{ title: "test2-1" }, { title: "test2-2" }, { title: "test2-3" }, { title: "test2-4" }, { title: "test2-5" }] },
  { key: "C", data: [{ title: "test3-2" }, { title: "test3-2" }] },
  { key: "W", data: [{ title: "test4-1" }, { title: "test4-2" }, { title: "test4-3" },{ title: "test4-4" }, { title: "test4-5" }, { title: "4-6" }] },
];
```

My custom render function like this:

```
  renderSectionItem = (info) => {
    console.log('what is _renderItem info =>');
    console.log(info);
    const txt = '  ' + info.item.theaterCn;
    return <Text
      style={{ height: 60, textAlignVertical: 'center', backgroundColor: "#ffffff", color: '#5C5C5C', fontSize: 15 }}>{txt}</Text>
  }

  sectionComp = (info) => {
    console.log('what is  _sectionComp info =>');
    console.log(info);
    const txt = info.section.key;
    return <Text
      style={{ height: 50, textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center', backgroundColor: '#9CEBBC', color: 'white', fontSize: 30 }}>{txt}</Text>
  }
```

I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using `movieData.length` or `movieData.length()` ?

Comment: No, i just put `movieData` into `sections` . My `movieData` structure just like the photo i upload.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The data structure `movieData` is not correct, `SectionList` expect an array of objects where each object should have `title` and `data` property, take a look at the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html). So, as per your `movieData`, you need to transform the values into that structure, like

**Sample**

First, transform the fetched data into the proper structure

```
fetch('https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api/getCloseTime?city=Hsinchu&sTime=18&eTime=21')
.then(r => r.json())
.then(r => {
  const movieData = r.reduce((r,s) => {
    r.push({title: s.theater, data: s.movie});
    return r;
  }, []);

  this.setState({ movieData });
});
```

Once you have transformed the data, just pass it to `SectionList`

```
<SectionList
      renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item.enName}</Text>}
      renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
      )}
      sections={this.state.movieData}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.enName + index}
/>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I don't know `should have title and data` at first. You save me a lots of days. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error:

**Cannot Read Property of Undefined length from  deltaPatcher.js**

**My solution was to using React Native Debugger instead of browser console.**

just dropping it , soo it might be help to someone.